# How to put data from the database to the template

Tags: database, magento

I want to put data from my database into my template file. This data will be selected based on user id.

I have the template file set up and I have the code to select a user based on their id, what I don't know and have been unable to work out is where the code that selects the data needs to be placed i.e. block, helper etc...

I assume its needs to go in a block, from there I don't know how I would get the data to the template and place each piece of data into their respective input fields?

my questions are:

- where would the code go
- how do I call that code from the template

===EDIT===

Namespace/Module/Block/Blockname.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Blockname.php
extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function postsGetByIdAction($id)
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $prefs = Mage::getModel('module/model');
    $prefs->load($params['id']);
    $data = $prefs->getData();
    return$data;
}
}
```

template/namespace/module/templatefile.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->postsGetById(); ?>//returns invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::postsGetById(Array())
```

I have tried var_dump as the error message said 'array' at the end but I still get the same message

Comment: Why don't you try learning magento before coding anything ? Try http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/magento-mvc.png or http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table or google it to understand the PVC layers of magento

Comment: @Bixi two reasons, 1. Magento is such a large platform it would take so long to go through and learn, then by the time you come to use it, its forgotten so the answer to that us use it and pick up as you go 2. the only way to truly learn something is use it

Comment: Before trying to code anything on whatever framework I do 1 or 2 tutorial and try to understand the basics, and after that I try to understand a full existing module... And I also try to not pollute stackoverflow with this type of post :)

Comment: but you will pollute it with unnecessary comments:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento works in this way, in MVC design pattern, is different to the usual MVC.
In Magento we have:
- Model
- View :
   - Blocks
   - Layouts
   - Templates
     The blocks grabs the data from the model, and pass this data to the template, all through   the layout system.
- Controllers

So, the answer to your question is that your need a method in one model, and invoke it through the block, and then, pass the data in this way:
block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Myblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getMyProductData()
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        return $product;    
    }
}
```

And then you can retrieve it in your phtml like this:

```
$_product = $this->getMyProductData();
echo $_product->getName();
```

Greetings from México :D

Comment: thanks for your help. That was what I think i've been trying, I must have got something wrong somewhere, could you please take a look at my edit to see what if you can see where the problem could be?